# Pyinstaller: Missing optional dependency 'openpyxl'

Tags: python, pyinstaller, openpyxl, exe, importerror

**Update**: By switiching from Anaconda (Python) to Python (standalone), creating a virtual enviroment and run everything within this environment, it worked perfectly fine! So I can recommend this if you encounter the same error as me.

I want to make an executable file from my Python script (Python version 3.11.5, Anaconda) using Pyinstaller. The main function of the script is to access data from an excel file and provide this data in different files for other scripts. When I run the script in Spyder it works totally fine. However, if I use `pyinstaller`, the following error occurs:

```
ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'openpyxl'.  Use pip or conda to install openpyxl.
[24544] Failed to execute script 'mwe' due to unhandled exception!
```

I reinstalled `openpyxl` and also in Anaconda it is displayed as *installed*. I further created a new environment as recommended in some other posts about this problem. I tried `pyinstaller --hidden-import openpyxl`. Furthermore I tried `pyinstaller --name=mwe --onefile mwe.py` and then to add `hiddenimports=[ 'openpyxl']' to the resulting` mwe.spec` file.
But nothing worked so far. As I am pretty new to Python and especially to pyinstaller, I would be glad if somenone could help me.

Here is a MWE where the error already occurs (just accessing the Excel file):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os


path = (pd.read_excel('MWE.xlsx', usecols='C', header=2)).iat[0, 0]
print(path)
```